# How to do Ctrl+Shift+[ on a Swiss French / German keyboard?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

In vscode or vim it is possible to fold/unfold blocks with Ctrl+Shift+[. However in the swiss french keyboard the `[` symbol is done with `AltGr+è`, so `Ctrl+Shift+AltGr+è` doesn't work.

Any hint?

Comment: VSC allows you to change hotkeys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ctrl+shift+`'` and ctrl+shift+`^`, i.e., the two keys left of backspace.

(Hat tip to http://www.kbdedit.com/, whose author told me.)